# group by excluding some values of a column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsqldeveloper

There are many values in a column such as example
for Stationery table.
I would like to have the count of pencil, Pen, notebook etc. I can achieve this by using DECODE very easily. However, if I want to exclude the Pencil, Pen and notebook and count rest of them in one common group "Others". How could we do it?

Comment: Could you please post some sample data, the query you are using and the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the column name is `ITEM` and the table is named `STATIONERY` and the column items you name specifically are `Pencil`, `Pen`, and `Notebook` then try:

```
SELECT CASE item
         WHEN 'Pencil' THEN 'Pencil'
         WHEN 'Pen' THEN 'Pen'
         WHEN 'Notebook' THEN 'Notebook'
         ELSE 'Others'
       END AS item_type, 
       count(*)
  FROM stationery
 GROUP BY CASE item
            WHEN 'Pencil' THEN 'Pencil'
            WHEN 'Pen' THEN 'Pen'
            WHEN 'Notebook' THEN 'Notebook'
            ELSE 'Others'
          END;
```

Comment: Thank you, But I need the count of it.

Comment: Count of what? What I have given you should provide the count (that's what the `COUNT(*)` is doing).